# Grapehene doesn't execute query

Tags: python, graphene-python

I have the following Graphene implementation:

```
import graphene
import json
import psycopg2
import re

connection = psycopg2.connect(user='postgres', password='Steppen1!', host='127.0.0.1', port='5432', database='TCDigital')
cursor = connection.cursor()

paths = {}

class PathError(Exception):
    def __init__(self, referencing, referenced):
        self.message = "entity {} has no relation with entity {}".format(referencing, referenced)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.message

def get_columns(entity):
    columns = {}

    cursor.execute("SELECT ordinal_position, column_name FROM information_schema.columns WHERE table_name = '{}'".format(entity))
    resultset = cursor.fetchall()

    i = 1
    for entry in resultset:
        columns[entry[1]] = i
        i = i + 1

    return columns

def get_previous_annotate(name, entity, related_column, id):
    columns = get_columns(entity)
    related_position = columns[related_column]-1

    entity_content = paths[name][entity]
    entity_content_filtered = [entry for entry in entity_content if entry['entry'][related_position] == id]
    
    annotate_to_return = sum(list(map(lambda entry: entry['annotate'], entity_content_filtered)))

    return annotate_to_return

def calculate_annotate_operation(entity, entry, entity_columns, operation, operands):
    operand1 = entity_columns[operands[0]]
    operand2 = entity_columns[operands[1]]

    if operation == '_sum':
        return entry[operand1] + entry[operand2]
    elif operation == '_mult':
        return entry[operand1] * entry[operand2]
    elif operation == '_div':
        return entry[operand1] / entry[operand2]
    elif operation == '_rest':
        return entry[operand1] - entry[operand2]
    else:
        return None

def get_annotated_value(name, entity, entry, annotate, entity_columns):
    if  annotate[0] != '_':
        column = entity_columns[annotate]
        column_value = entity[column['ordinal_position']]

        return column_value
    elif annotate == '_count':
        return 1
    else:
        operation = annotate.split('(')
        if operation[0] in ['_sum', '_mult', '_div', '_rest']:
            operands_base = operation[1].split(')')[0]
            operands = operands_base.split(',')
            return calculate_annotate_operation(operation[0], operands)
        else:
            raise "Operación no permitida: {}".format(annotate)

def get_annotate(name, entity, entry, entity_columns, previous_entity, related_column, annotate):
    annotated_value = None
    previous_entity_columns = get_columns(previous_entity)

    if previous_entity:
        annotated_value = get_previous_annotate(name, previous_entity, related_column, entry[entity_columns['id']-1])
    else:
        annotated_value = get_annotated_value(name, entity, entry, annotate, entity_columns)

    #print({'name': name, 'entity': entity, 'entry': entry, 'annotated_value': annotated_value})

    return annotated_value

def populate_entity(name, entity, entity_columns, previous_entity, previous_entity_relationship_column, annotate):
    cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM {}'.format(entity))
    resultset = cursor.fetchall()

    paths[name][entity] = []
    for entry in resultset:
        if previous_entity:
            entry_annotate = get_annotate(name, entity, entry, entity_columns, previous_entity, previous_entity_relationship_column, annotate)
        else:
            entry_annotate = get_annotate(name, entity, entry, entity_columns, previous_entity, None, annotate)

        paths[name][entity].append({'entry': entry, 'entity_columns': entity_columns, 'annotate': entry_annotate, 'previos_entity': previous_entity, 'previous_entity_relationship_column': previous_entity_relationship_column})

def create_path(name, entities, annotate):
    paths[name] = {}

    previous_entity = None
    for entity in reversed(entities):
        previous_entity_relationship_column = None
        if previous_entity:
            previous_entity_relationships = get_foreign_relationships(previous_entity)
            previous_entity_relationship = [relationship for relationship in previous_entity_relationships if relationship[5] == entity][0]
            previous_entity_relationship_column = previous_entity_relationship[3]

        entity_columns = get_columns(entity)
        populate_entity(name, entity, entity_columns, previous_entity, previous_entity_relationship_column, annotate)
        previous_entity = entity

def get_foreign_relationships(entity):
        cursor.execute('''
            SELECT 
                tc.table_schema, tc.constraint_name, tc.table_name, kcu.column_name, ccu.table_schema AS foreign_table_schema, ccu.table_name AS foreign_table_name, ccu.column_name AS foreign_column_name 
            FROM information_schema.table_constraints AS tc 
            JOIN information_schema.key_column_usage AS kcu ON tc.constraint_name = kcu.constraint_name
            AND tc.table_schema = kcu.table_schema
            JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu ON ccu.constraint_name = tc.constraint_name
            AND ccu.table_schema = tc.table_schema
            WHERE tc.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY' AND tc.table_name='{}';'''.format(entity))
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        result_array = []

        for record in result:
            new_entity = Entity(name=record[5])
            result_array.append(new_entity)

        return result

def is_relationship(referencing, referenced):
    foreign_relationships = get_foreign_relationships(referencing)

    if referenced in list(map(lambda relationship: relationship[5], foreign_relationships)):
        return True
    else:
        return False

def traverse(entities, direction):
    for i in range(len(entities)):
        if i > 0 and i < len(entities)-1:
            if not is_relationship(entities[i], entities[i-1]):
                raise PathError(entities[i], entities[i-1])

    return True

def validate_path(path):
    entities = path.split('/')
    
    traverse(entities, 'forward')

    return entities

def get_path_step(name, step, key):
    content = paths[name][step]

    if key is None:
        filtered_content = [{'entry': entry['entry'], 'annotate': entry['annotate']} for entry in content]
    else:
        if content['previous_entity_relationship_column'] is not None:
            previous_entity_relationship_column = content['previous_entity_relationship_column']
            relationship_column_index = content['entity_columns'][previous_entity_relationship_column]
            filtered_content = [{'entry': entry['entry'], 'annotate': entry['annotate']} for entry in content if entry[relationship_column_index] == key]

    return filtered_content

class Entity(graphene.ObjectType):
    name = graphene.String()
    annotate = graphene.Float()
    content = graphene.Field(graphene.List(lambda: Entity))

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    entity_relationships = graphene.List(Entity, entity=graphene.String())
    postgresql_version = graphene.String
    path = graphene.String(name=graphene.String(), path=graphene.String(), annotate=graphene.String(), current=graphene.String(), key=graphene.Int())
    path_step = graphene.String(name=graphene.String(), step=graphene.String(), key=graphene.Int())

    @staticmethod
    def resolve_path_step(parent, info, name, step, key):
        
        path_step = get_path_step(name, step, key)
        print(name)
        print(step)
        print(key)
        print(path_step)

        return path_step

    @staticmethod
    def resolve_path(parent, info, name, path, annotate, current, key):
        entities = validate_path(path)

        create_path(name, entities, annotate)
        
        content_to_return = get_path_step(name, entities[0], None)

        return content_to_return

    @staticmethod
    def resolve_entity_relationships(parent, info, entity):
        result_array = get_foreign_relationships(entity)

        return result_array

    @staticmethod
    def resolve_postgresql_version(parent, info):
        cursor.execute("SELECT version();")
        record = cursor.fetchone()
        return record

def execute_query(query_to_execute):
    queries = {
        'postgresqlVersion': '''
            {
                postgresqlVersion
            }
        ''',
        'entityRelationships': '''
            {
                entityRelationships (entity: "inventory_productitem") {
                    name
                }
            }
        ''',
        'path': '''
            {
                path(name: "Ventas", path: "general_state/general_city/inventory_store/operations_sale", annotate: "_count", current: "inventory_product", key: 0)
            }
        ''',
        'path_step': '''
            {
                path_step(name: "Ventas", step: "inventory_store", key: 27)
            }
        '''
    }

    schema = graphene.Schema(query=Query)

    result = schema.execute(queries[query_to_execute])
    dict_result = dict(result.data.items())
    print(json.dumps(dict_result, indent=2))
    
    result2 = schema.execute(queries['path_step'])
    dict_result2 = dict(result2.data.items())
    print(json.dumps(dict_result2, indent=2))

execute_query('path')
```

Te first call to `schema.execute()` works with no problem, but the second one doesn't even enter the resolver, and the only error message I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "query.py", line 249, in <module>
    execute_query('path')
  File "query.py", line 246, in execute_query
    dict_result2 = dict(result2.data.items())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I don't know what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that the problem was that I am making a pythonic pascal-cased call to Graphene query: `path_step(name: "Ventas", step: "inventory_store", key: 27)`, but Graphene requieres queries to be called on a camel-cased fashion, even when the name of the resolvers and query variables are pascal-cased in the code.

So the call to the query must by camel-cased like this: `pathStep(name: "Ventas", step: "inventory_store", key: 27)`